# How to calculate the vectors associated with the transformation of a 2D triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I’m working [through Kahn Academy](https://youtu.be/MIAmN5kgp3k?t=777) (link goes to point in video where he explains what is happening below) and there’s a part of the vector math for the transformation of a 2D triangle that I do not understand. Below is a transformed triangle based originally on the following vectors:

$\vec{x_0}={[-2,2]}, \vec{x_1}=[-2,2], \vec{x_2}=[2,-2]$

with transformation:

$
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & -1 \\
    2 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$

[image: Linear Transformation]

What confuses me is how he came up with what is shown in the picture as the line segment $T(L_0)$. The equation he derived for the transformation is $T(L_0)={T(\vec{x_0})-t(T(\vec{x_1})-T(\vec{x_0})) | 0 \le t \le 1}$. If you calculate $T(\vec{x_1})=[-4,-4]$ and $T(\vec{x_0})=[0,4]$. He underlines in purple in purple the line segment $T(\vec{x_1})-T(\vec{x_0})$ which is then indicated on the graph at $T(L_0)$ but where I'm lost is that yes, that is indeed the line segment $T(\vec{x_1})-T(\vec{x_0})$  but it looks like the rest of the equation was ignored. What happened to the $T(\vec{x_0})$? Subtracting $T(\vec{x_1})-T(\vec{x_0})$ from $T(\vec{x_0})$ creates a different line segment than what is shown (I thought). Specifically you get $[0,-4]-t([-4,-4]-[0,-4])$ which seems like it would be everything between the vector $[0,-4]-([0,0]$ up to $[-4,0])$

Answer (score 1):

After staring what I wrote myself I just realized the answer. You can imagine this as you start at the position vector (the point) $[0, -4]$ and then you draw a line starting there at every point (remember there's a $t$ to account for) all the way to $[-4, 0]$. Key to remember is that this is *not* starting at the origin, it is a line segment starting at $[0, -4]$ being drawn four points negatively so it's final point is $[-4,-4]$